# Block macOS updates beyond a specific version level?

Tags: software-update

I need to prevent one of my macs from upgrading beyond macOS 12.2.1 and I'm trying to work out if there is a configuration that can block this.

I have an application that still relies on Python 2.  MacOS 12.3 removes Python 2 support.  The developer doesn't think a fix will be available until later this year, but I need the application.

I downgraded the mac to 12.2 (oddly ... this is the *only* version that it would let me install.  It blocked installation of any other version I tried -- even erasing the system volume wouldn't let me install anything else).

Unfortunately after that install worked, we tried to update it to 12.2.1 (the last version prior to 12.3) via `softwareupdate` command and while it appeared to work, the mac ended up on 12.3.1 anyway.

In an enterprise environment, I realize it's possible to block OS updates until they are permitted.

Is there a way to do this on a personal mac?

Comment: In this case why not just install python 2 from python.org or from a package manager like conda, macports, homebrew etc. Also if the app is relying on unsupported software like Python 2 what else is not maintained and has possible security issues? You have security issues anyway as the macOS upgrades you don't install have security fixes. (Also note that any app depending on python should have included python in its own bundle as Apple has suggested for years)

Comment: @mmmmmm Initially we did try to install Python 2 ... but found the developer hard-coded the path to Python 2 (rather than relying on the environment path to find it) -- so that didn't work.  
I agree with your concern regarding not being able to apply security patches.  This puts us in a bit of a compromise.  The developer had at least 8 years notice but did nothing to port to Python 3.  
I did manually revert my macOS back to 12.2. ... but when attempted to upgrade to just 12.2.1 the mac continued to applky upgrades to 12.3.1 (which breaks the functionality I need).

Comment: Well a fix for the hard coding should be quick -

Answer (score 1):

Of course.  Disable the checkbox in System Preferences.

[image: Software Update in System Preferences]
[image: Advanced dialog from Software Update]

Comment: We did do this from the GUI. But we also attempted to use the command-line `softwareupdate` command to update to macOS 12.2.1 -- the latest version prior to 12.3.   Upon doing this .. instead of stopping at 12.2.1 the system continued to update all the way to 12.3.1.

I am attempting to learn if I can block updates beyond a specific release of macOS regardless of update method.  I am trying to do this on a personal mac.  My corporate owned mac does this already -- under control of commercial MDM software.  Can I do use manually?

Comment: Software update is always going to offer you the most current.  Not versions below that.